# Having trouble performing a GET request

Tags: get, httprequest, google-fusion-tables

Im going through the documentation for using Fusion Table's API and I am having trouble executing HTTP Requests.
For example, I copy and pasted this request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables/1e7y6mtqv891111111111_aaaaaaaaa_CvWhg9gc
```

into my URL bar. What I want is to see the table with

```
table ID = "1e7y6mtqv891111111111_aaaaaaaaa_CvWhg9gc"
```

Instead, google does a search on the above code.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just copy paste that with "GET" in your address bar.

If you would like to just see the result of the GET operation you can paste

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables/1e7y6mtqv891111111111_aaaaaaaaa_CvWhg9gc
```

to your URL bar as your browser will do the "GET" here.

For making POST request however you may need to use some extension or tool like POSTMAN but for a simple "GET" request this will do.

I would request you to read up on HTTP GET/POST operations.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp